# Solr, Unable to execute query during dataimport

Tags: solr, data-import

I use many tables for indexing.
These tables are also used by crawler for insert, update during dataimport.

During dataimport, I get errors for some tables like "Unable to execute query". But next time, when I try to dataimport for that table, I can do successfully without any error.

```
[Thread-17] ERROR o.a.s.h.d.EntityProcessorWrapper - Exception in entity : 
test_5:org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: 
Unable to execute query: 
SELECT Title, url, synonym, description FROM test_5 WHERE status in ('1','s')  Processing Document # 11046

at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException.wrapAndThrow(DataImportHandlerException.java:72)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.<init>(JdbcDataSource.java:253)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSource.java:210)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSource.java:39)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.initQuery(SqlEntityProcessor.java:59)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.nextRow(SqlEntityProcessor.java:73)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorWrapper.nextRow(EntityProcessorWrapper.java:238)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:596)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.java:268)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:187)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:359)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:427)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter$1.run(DataImporter.java:408)

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet is from UPDATE. No Data.
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:982)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:927)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.next(ResultSetImpl.java:7152)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.loadServerVariables(ConnectionImpl.java:3870)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer(ConnectionImpl.java:3407)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2384)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2153)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:792)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor12.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:381)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:305)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$1.call(JdbcDataSource.java:161)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$1.call(JdbcDataSource.java:128)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getConnection(JdbcDataSource.java:363)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.access$200(JdbcDataSource.java:39)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.<init>(JdbcDataSource.java:240)
... 11 more
```

I set the connettimeout, readtimeout in data-config.xml but I often get this error.
If I use tables for dataimport which are used by other processs(insert, update, delete), Do I get error like this? How Can I index all of my tables?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting "readOnly=True" in the data-config.xml file.

```
  <dataSource 
    type="JdbcDataSource"  
    driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
    url="jdbc:mysql://my.ip/my_db" 
    user="my_db_user" 
    password="my_password" 
    readOnly="True"
  />
```

Comment: I set it but get the same error even I stop all of robot(insert/update). How Should I do? Help me~